# programmatic textblock entry with linebreaks

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

How do I programmatically add text with line breaks to a textblock?

If I insert text like this:

```
helpBlock.Text = "Here is some text. <LineBreak/> Here is <LineBreak/> some <LineBreak/> more.";
```

Then the linebreaks get interpreted as part of the string literal. I want it to be more like what would happen if I had it in the XAML.

I can't seem to do it the WPF way either:

```
helpBlock.Inlines.Add("Here is some content.");
```

Since the Add() method wants to accept objects of type "inline".

I can't create an Inline object and pass it as a parameter because it is "inaccessible due to its protection level:

```
helpBlock.Inlines.Add(new Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Inline("More text"));
```

I don't see a way to programmatically add runs.

I can find a ton of WPF examples of this, but nothing for WinRT.

I've also turned up a lot of XAML examples, but nothing from C#.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could just pass in newline `\n` instead of `<LineBreak/>`

```
helpBlock.Text = "Here is some text. \n Here is \n some \n more.";
```

Or in Xaml you would use the `Hex` value of newline

```
 <TextBlock Text="Here is some text. &#x0a; Here is &#x0a; some &#x0a; more."/>
```

Both results:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there is an advantage to doing \r\n instead of \n.

Comment: I marked this the best answer because it is so simple and will probably simplify things for loading from an XML file.

Answer (score 9):

Use Enviroment.NewLine

```
testText.Text = "Testing 123" + Environment.NewLine + "Testing ABC";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
builder.Append("Test Text");
builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
builder.Append("Test 2 Text");
testText.Text += builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `\n` to `<LineBreak/>` programmatically.

```
    string text = "This is a line.\nThis is another line.";
    IList<string> lines = text.Split(new string[] { @"\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        tb.Inlines.Add(line);
        tb.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I would use "\n" instead of linebreaks. Best way would be use it on this way:

*Resources.resx file:*

```
myTextline: "Here is some text. \n Here is \n some \n more."
```

In yours Class:

```
helpBlock.Text = Resources.myTextline;
```

This will looks like:

[image]

Other solution would be to build your string here with Environment.NewLine.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
builder.Append(Resources.line1);
builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
builder.Append(Resources.line2);
helpBlock.Text += builder.ToString();
```

Or use here "\n"

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("\n");
builder.Append(Resources.line1);
builder.Append("\n");
builder.Append(Resources.line2);
helpBlock.Text += builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one component XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textLog" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="#FFDEDEDE"/>
```

Then I pass the string + Environment.NewLine;

Example:

```
textLog.Inlines.Add("Inicio do processamento " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + Environment.NewLine);
textLog.Inlines.Add("-----------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
```

The result is

Inicio do processamento 19/08/2019 20:31:13 
-----------------------------------