# How can I insert a newline into a TextBlock without XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a WPF `TextBlock` inside a `Label` **in code** (XAML is not possible in my case) as follows:

```
Label l = new Label();
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
l.Content = tb;
```

I then come to a situation where I need to set the `.Text` property of `TextBlock` containing a new line, such as:

```
tb.Text = "Hello\nWould you please just work?";
```

I have tried numerous encodings (HTML encoding, ASCII encoding, etc.) of various newline combinations (carriage return, linefeed, carriage return plus linefeed, linefeed plus carriage return, double linefeed, double carriage return, etc... ad nauseum).

- Answers should contain *absolutely no XAML*.
- Answers should assume that the original objects were created using C# code and **not** XAML.
- Answers should not refer to *binding* of WPF properties. No binding is being used. The "Text" property of the "TextBlock" object is being **set**. The newline *must* be inserted *there*.

If this is impossible, please let me know how I can programmatically add newlines by dynamically replacing each newline in an arbitrary input `String` into a `LineBreak` object (or whatever is needed to get this working). The input `String` will have arbitrary (readable text) contents that I am unable to anticipate in advance because the text itself is dynamic (user-defined); the source strings will have the linefeed character (aka LF, aka `\n`) but I can easily replace that with whatever is needed.

Also, if it is easier to do this with a `Label` directly rather than a `TextBlock` in a `Label`, that is good too -- I can use that. I just need a control with automatic plain text line wrapping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [programmatic textblock entry with linebreaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582398/programmatic-textblock-entry-with-linebreaks), and actually the second answer there is likely the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have a few choices:

Use the `Environment.NewLine` property:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "Would you please just work?";
```

Or, manually add `Run`s and `LineBreak`s to the `TextBlock`:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello"));
tb.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("Would you please just work?"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another small note. I had a similar problem and took the string from a resource file. What I noticed is that .NET delivered the string "\r\n" as "\\r\\n". When I corrected that by replacing the double-backslashes with normal backslashes everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can store string values in "Resources.resw", and get them in code directly.
In the VS resource editor itself not possible to add empty lines to string values. To do this, just edit value in **any text editor**, add empty lines how many you need, and "Copy -> Paste" to **Value** column of Visual Studio's resource editor.

**For example:** value of **"Farewell"** with 2 line breaks: **Goodbye\n\nSave changes?** - will look like this in text editor (and **as it is**, need to be copied to VS):

> *Goodbye*
>
> *Save changes?*

[image]

To get string value of the resource in C# code, call 1 of the following lines (UWP or WinUI3), depending on your application.

**UWP code:**

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("Farewell");
```

**WinUI3 code:**

```
new ResourceLoader().GetString("Farewell");
```